# Overriding Custom module's controller in Magento2 giving error

Tags: magento2, overrides, controllers, extend, preference

I am trying to override the controller of an extension in Magento2.

My di.xml file is:-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
      <preference for="Mycustom\Custom\Controller\Adminhtml\Controllerfolder\Fileaction" type="ActualModule\Custom\Controller\Adminhtml\Controllerfolder\Fileaction"/>

</config>
```

I have cloned the controller file with updated namespaces, and extend the controller to module's file like:-

```
<?php

namespace Mycustom\Custom\Controller\Adminhtml\Controllerfolder;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory;

use ActualModule\Custom\Model\OrderFactory;

class Fileaction extends \ActualModule\Custom\Controller\Adminhtml\Controllerfolder\Fileaction
{
    /**
     * @var OrderFactory
     */
    protected $_modelOrderFactory;

    public function __construct(Context $context, Filter $filter, CollectionFactory $collectionFactory, 
        OrderFactory $modelOrderFactory)
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $filter);
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->_modelOrderFactory = $modelOrderFactory;
    }
    protected  function massAction(AbstractCollection $collection)
{

    die('here');
 }
```

It should be functional but the issue I get on `php bin/magento s:d:c` is as follow:-

Errors during compilation:

```
    ActualModule\Custom\Controller\Adminhtml\Controllerfolder\Fileaction
                Missed required argument collectionFactory in parent::__construc
t call. File: C:/wamp64/www/magento/app/code/Mycustom\Custom\Controller\Adminhtml\Controllerfolder/Fileaction.php
Total Errors Count: 1
Errors during compilation:
```

I feel like I missed something but not able to catch what.

Just to add var/generation, di etc.. clearing has been done, cache flushed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repalce your controller constructer like this.

```
public function __construct(Context $context, Filter $filter, CollectionFactory $collectionFactory, 
        OrderFactory $modelOrderFactory)
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $filter,$collectionFactory,$modelOrderFactory);
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->_modelOrderFactory = $modelOrderFactory;
    }
```

Comment: The code seems to work, but I am just checking that it overrides too. Also I request you to please explain a bit why the same function did not gave any error when it is being used in module's controller, but gave error in my module. I have understood the issue in my code though, but just curious to know in more depth. Thanks in advance

Comment: If my answer help you, please accept it. So it will help other in community.

Comment: For the magento2 overiding concept, you need to pass all required pararameter to parent controller.

Comment: Actually it did not override the controller, but resolved the s:d:c issue.

Comment: If my answer help you, please accept it. So it will help other in community.

Comment: I have accepted, but it will be better if you can more info on why is the module not overriding the controller?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72167/discussion-between-dhiren-vasoya-and-gagandeep).

Comment: I already give you answer that, For the magento2 overiding concept, you need to pass all required pararameter to parent controller.